# Button not on the right side of text input since jquery mobile 1.2.0

Tags: jquery-mobile

After upgrading to jquery mobile 1.2.0 I can't put the button on the right side of the text input field.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
             <input type="text" data-inline="true"/>
             <button data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Send</button>
         </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed that removing the data-type="horizontal" and added a class with style="float: right;" to the button.